# Reading Busy Flag of SSD1803 via SPI not working

Tags: c, stm32, spi

The SSD1803 is a controller which is used to control an LCD-Display. I'm using SPI to communicate with the controller, which works fine for normal instructions: I can print text onto the display, clearing the display, storing my custom characters in the RAM, setting the cursor, etc. 
But now I want to read the Busy Flag (`BF`), which isn't working properly-> The byte which contains the `BF` always returns `0`.

#### Command Table

| Instruction | RE | RS | R/W | DB7 | DB6 | DB5 | DB4 | DB3 | DB2 | DB1 | DB0 | Execution Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clear Display | X | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | **1.53ms** |
| Ready busy flag and address/part ID | X | 0 | 1 | **BF** | AC6/ID6 | AC5/ID5 | AC4/ID4 | AC3/ID3 | AC2/ID2 | AC1/ID1 | AC0/ID0 | 0us |

`BF = 1`: busy state
`BF = 0`: ready state

<sup>[SSD1803 Datasheet](https://www.lcd-module.com/fileadmin/eng/pdf/zubehoer/ssd1803_2_0.pdf) p. 29</sup>

---

#### Timing Diagram

[image: Timing_Diagram]

<sup>[SSD1803 Datasheet](https://www.lcd-module.com/fileadmin/eng/pdf/zubehoer/ssd1803_2_0.pdf) p. 27</sup>

---

#### IOC Config File

[image: IOC_File]

The clock frequency is `312.5kHz` which is in the external clock range of the controller:

[image: External_Clock]

<sup>[SSD1803 Datasheet](https://www.lcd-module.com/fileadmin/eng/pdf/zubehoer/ssd1803_2_0.pdf) p. 57</sup>

---

#### Code

```
   int LCDInstrHandler(void)
   {
     // Clear Display
•    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_LCD_NSS_GPIO_Port, SPI_LCD_NSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

     uint8_t tDataClear[3] = {0b11111000, 0b10000000, 0b00000000};
     HAL_StatusTypeDef tClearState = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&SPI_LCD, tDataClear, 3, 1000);

     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_LCD_NSS_GPIO_Port, SPI_LCD_NSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
     
     // Read Busy Flag
     uint8_t tDataBF[2] = {0b11111100, 0x00};
     uint8_t tRecBuf[2];

     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_LCD_NSS_GPIO_Port, SPI_LCD_NSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     HAL_StatusTypeDef tBFState = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SPI_LCD, tDataBF, tRecBuf, 2, 1000);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_LCD_NSS_GPIO_Port, SPI_LCD_NSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

•    return 0;
   }
```

<sup>`•` = Breakpoint</sup>

By default, there's a text on the display, which gets printed after the initialization. After that the function `LCDInstrHandler` gets called. 
As you can see in the IOC Config file, I set the First Bit to `MSB First`. Means the left bit is sent first and when I receive a byte, the left bit is the first bit the slave sent.

To test if the busy flag works, I send the clear display instruction, which takes **1.53ms**. This works: My display is cleared. After that, I send the start byte with `RS = 0` and `R/W = 1`, which tells the SSD1803 controller to return me a byte containing the `BF` in `DB7` (see Command Table).

The time between the first breakpoint and the second breakpoint is **150us** (measured with oscilloscope). Means that the `BF` instruction gets executed in time, so that the `BF` should be `1` since the SSD1803 controller is still executing the clear display instruction.

**What I get:**

- `tRecBuf`: `{0, 0}`
- `tClearState`, `tBFState`: `HAL_OK`

**What I expect**

- `tRecBuf`: `{0, 0bxxxxxxx1}`

  - `1`: `BF` (`DB7`) as LSB
  - `xxxxxxx`: `AC0-AC6`

---

#### Attachments

- [SSD1803 Controller Datasheet](https://www.lcd-module.com/fileadmin/eng/pdf/zubehoer/ssd1803_2_0.pdf)

Comment: Why do you think that the flag should be `1`?

Comment: @0___________ Because the SSD1803 is processing the `Clear Display` instruction which dues 1.53ms and I'm reading the `BF` within these 1.53ms.

Comment: What's "CPHA 2 Edge" even supposed to mean? SPI has two clock phase settings, CPHA=0 meaning clock edge happens half a bit length inside the data, CPHA=1 meaning data and clock edges are aligned. CPHA=2 means... what?

Comment: Do you have a 2 channel scope? Trigger on /CS falling edge and check if the actual data contains the 1 or not.

Comment: @Lundin "2 Edge" is `CPHA = 1` in code . Because I have a `HIGH` Polarity clock (if it doesn't clock, the clock line is on `HIGH`) and, as you can see in the timing diagram, the data should be clocked out on rising edge, I have to set the Clock Phase on "2 Edge".

Comment: Busy flag is transmitted with some other bits - `ACx/IDx`. Since these are received as zeros two, it looks like data reception doesn't work at all. Try to make an external loopback - disconnect the SSD1803 and connect MOSI to MISO directly. This way the mcu should receive it's own data with `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` function. If it still receives zero - then SPI or MISO pin is not configured correctly.

Comment: @Flexz Would be nice approach. The problem is, the SSD1803 is soldered on a bought LCD-Display and I can't reach the controller because it has thermal paste on it. Thanks though for you comment!

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot disconnect the MCU from the display?

Comment: Did you try to receive 2 bytes, as the second one will tell you the ID of the LCD controller? -- Please record the actual transmission, as Lundin suggested, and add it to your question.

Comment: OT: Why did you swap the bits of the bytes? The diagrams of the LCD controller show that LSBit is transmitted first. You will need to mirror all values in your program, compared to common notation.

Comment: @thebusybee Not the MCU. I can't reach the controller (SSD1803) of the LCD Display. Also, I measured the transmission. The CS is in time and the clock looks fine (same as in the timing diagram). The data line is on 0V (same as the data I receive).

Comment: @thebusybee I set in the IOC the first bit to MSB. Since the SSD1803 uses LSB, I swapped the bytes.

Comment: Concerning the MSB/LSB: Do want you want, I just wondered why you make life harder than necessary. -- The suggestion of Flexz was to separate the MCU from the LCD and to connect MOSI to MISO to check that on the MCU's side transmission works correctly. -- You might want to add your scope/analyzer recordings of the write/read cycles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems probable that the SOD line of the LCD controller isn't connected to your MCU. The fact that you're reading all 0's probably means that it's tied low on the breakout board. Most display breakout PCBs sold don't bother connecting the MISO/SOD line since the display is effectively a write-only device. Honestly very few people bother reading anything from these little displays because it isn't necessary. If you're worried about the display being busy after you send a clear command, then add a 1.53ms delay to your code to ensure you don't try to write too soon. If you absolutely need to read the status flag, then make your own LCD breakout PCB which properly connects all of the signal lines (not very difficult these days with KiCad and fabricators like JLCPCB).